# How to let only a certain percentage of turtles die every 10 ticks?

Tags: netlogo, die

After trying all somewhat applicable solutions here to no avail, I still would like to see if someone can help me with this.

I have a type of turtle (sexworkers) divided along a boolean variable [trust?] and want to make a certain percentage/certain number (not so important) of one of the two types exit the model [die] every 10 number of ticks.

I tried and failed with the following:

*tried to make half exit, **BUT: kills all or most, not half.** :*

```
ask n-of (count sexworkers / 2) sexworkers [ die ]
```

*this one works but kills too many. If there are more than 2 sexworkers on any given patch, all but one will die. Can I set this to percentage?*

```
ask patches with [count sexworkers-here >= 2]
[ ask one-of sexworkers-here [ ask other sexworkers-here[die]]
]
```

*this also kills all on each 10 ticks so too many for me*

```
ask sexworkers with [trust?][ if ticks - birth-tick > 10 [die] ]
```

**;all trusting sexworkers die when they are older than 10 ticks**

*should kill a certain percentage but the reporter variable is missing because of the boolean property instead of a number-based one*

```
ask min-n-of (0.5 * count sexworkers with [trust?]) sexworkers with [trust?] [XXXXXXREPORTERXXXX]
[die]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code is correct. Try this in a new model to see:

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 150 [set color red setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  print count turtles
  ask n-of (count turtles / 2) turtles [ die ]
  print count turtles
end
```

You describe the problem as the code killing too many. I suspect you called it multiple times. For example, try this version:

```
turtles-own [trust?]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 150
  [ set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set trust? random-float 1 < 0.1
  ]
  print count turtles
  print count turtles with [trust?]
  ask turtles with [trust?]
  [ ask n-of (count turtles / 2) turtles [ die ]
    print count turtles
  ]
end
```

It assigns 10% of the turtles as having TRUE trust? and then asks each of those turtles to kill half the turtles still alive. Did you do something like that?

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't include the first ask turtles with [trust?] before the ask n-of, that was it! Now it runs smoothly!

Comment: @MiraFey - If JenB's answer has resolved your issue, please click the little check mark near the top of their answer to mark this question as closed.